# A necessary and sufficient condition for symmetry of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Prove that if $X$ is an integrable random variable, it has a symmetric distribution if and only if: 
$$E(X|X^2)=0$$ 
Can anyone check my solution?

Firstly $$EX=0$$
Then we have:
$$E(E(X|X^2))=EX=0$$ 
Secondly: 
$$E(X|X^2)=0 $$ 
So:
$$E(X)=E(E(X|X^2)=E(0)=0$$

I will be grateful for help!Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your approach is that you confuse the assertions "the distribution of $X$ is symmetric" and "$X$ is centered".

Notice that if $B$ is a symmetric Borel set (i.e. $B=-B$), then $\{X\in B\}$ is measurable for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X^2$. Conversely, an element of $\sigma(X^2)$ is of the form $\{X\in B\}$ for some symmetric $B$.

Assume that $\mathbb E[X\mid X^2]=0$. Then for each symmetric $B$, we have $\mathbb E[X\mathbb 1_{\{X\in B\}}]=0$.

Conversely, if $X$ is symmetric, then we can compute $\mathbb E[X\mathbb 1_{\{X\in B\}}]$ where $B$ is symmetric and link this with $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X \mid X^2]\mathbb 1_{\{X\in B\}}]$.

Comment: I am thinking about your solution for a while and honestly I can't figure it out. Would you be so kind to give me some more details?

Comment: Which steps in particular are problematic for you? Once you precise it, I will give the details.

Comment: Firstly, I don't understand the whole idea. If $X$ is not centered and distribution is symmetric. Is it symmetric to a vertical curve? Assuming, that yes I don't know why we are using symmetric Borel. Also, I am wondering why $\mathbb E[X\mathbb 1_{\{X\in B\}}]=0$.

Comment: Symmetric means that the random variables $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, that is, $\mathbb P(X\leqslant t)=\mathbb P(-X\leqslant t)$ for each real  number $t$.